# Only part of row copied to another table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

So I have a workbook to copy a row based on it's ITEMNO to another table in another sheet.

But my problem is that I can't seem to copy the entire row. E.g

Sheet1[image]

The way it's supposed to work is that once you select a value from the select list it should add that row to the end of the table on the next sheet seen below

Sheet2[image]

Only the ITEMNO is added.

Can someone tell me what's missing in the following VBA that needs fixing?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x, i As Long, lRow As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, [SerialNumber]) Is Nothing Then
    i = Application.Match(Target, [Table1[ITEMNO]], 0)
    x = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows(i).Range
    With Sheet2
        If .[a2] = "" Then lRow = 2 Else lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(lRow, 1) = Array(x(1, 1), x(1, 2), x(1, 5), x(1, 6), x(1, 8))
    End With
End If

End Sub

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x, lRow As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, [Table1[ITEMNO]]) Is Nothing Then
    x = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows(Target.Row - 2).Range
    With Sheet2
        If .[a2] = "" Then lRow = 2 Else lRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(lRow, 1) = _
        Array(Target, Target.Offset(, 1), Target.Offset(, 2), Target.Offset(, 3), Target.Offset(, 4), Target.Offset(, 5), Target.Offset(, 6), Target.Offset(, 7))
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

SerialNumber is what's selected in the dropdown list. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Cells(lRow, 1) = Array(...)
```

You are attempting to assign an array but only specifying the first cell. (`Cells` represents a single cell.)

You need to extend the range across the columns:

```
.Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, 11)) = Array(...)
```

Rather than using the *magic number* 11, though, it is preferable to store and reuse a variable containing the value `Range("K1").Column`.

---

Better yet would be to name the table and use `Columns.Count` to always identify the last column.